# Multibinding and binding to view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Let's say this code sets label's content:

```
    <Label.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                <Binding ElementName="EmailTextBox" Path="(Validation.Errors)"/>
                <Binding ElementName="PhoneNumberTextBox" Path="(Validation.Errors)"/>
                <Binding ElementName="MobileNumberTextBox" Path="(Validation.Errors)"/>
            </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
```

And it works fine, but (in this case) is it possible to bind label's content to the view model, so the  view model is immediately notified about label's content change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want Label.Content to be reflected in property in ViewModel, am I right?

Comment: Post code for converter. What it do?

Comment: @Maximus exactly. Obviously I could do it using binding, but here I am already using multibinding.

Comment: @RohitVats Each Validation.Errors is an ObservableCollection, converter searches for a first non empty collection and returns its first element (so simply saying Label shows first found error message).

Answer (score 1):

I came up solution and it seems to be working, you need to create your own Label, subsequently add DependencyProperty which will be assigned every time when the Content is changed. Unfortunately, there is no event like ContentChanged indicating that Content was changed so I had to add this in own Label as well. Take a look and let me know whether it works.

```
class MyLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyContent", typeof(string), typeof(MyLabel));
    public string MyContent
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyContentProperty, value); }
    }

    static MyLabel()
    {
        ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyLabel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnContentChanged)));

    }
    private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyLabel obj = d as MyLabel;
        if (obj != null)
            obj.MyContent = obj.Content.ToString();
    }
}
```

and XAML looks as follows

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <local:MyLabel Content="Content" MyContent="{Binding Zmienna, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Now in property Zmienna you have your Content value.